Idiom in english meaning "You need intelligence to cheat"?
Indians are famous for cheating ( for e.g. entire movie industry -- called Bollywood), entire IT industry (Amazon clone, UBER clone etc.).
There is a famous idiom in Hindi which loosely translates to You need intelligence to cheat. Hindi words for cheat and intelligence rhyme, which is what makes the idiom witty.
The idiom is used in the scenarios where the copied item is of inferior quality and the speaker wants to dismiss the copied product, and its creator (for shamelessly copying someone else, and failing at it).
Is there idiom in English language resembling that?
Also, Indians are copying various aspects of western culture, and failing at it (IMHO). So, the hindi idiom applies for this scenario as well.

I have come across statements like "if you are not cheating you are not trying hard enough". But English sayings tend to be disapproving of cheating or copying, and the expression "It is a copy of A" suggests an inferior copy.

The classical composer Igor Stravinsky supposedly said, "Good composers borrow, great ones steal," basically saying that all composers get ideas from previous works, but only the truly great ones transform them into something new in the process.

Could you please replace "cheating" with "imitating" in your first sentence ? I think you meant that. My experience in the Gulf is that Indians are appreciated for their honesty and hard work.

@JamesMathai Thank you for your answer. However, I think every group is hard-working (I used to work in USA), and significant number of Indians are dishonest and take advantage of kindness of others for e.g. taking advantage of return policy of stores like Target (US based store) --  Buying stuff, using it for a week, and returning it and getting full refund; true story.

I think OP has this phrase in mind
Nakal karne ko akal chahiye.
(Correct me if I am wrong. I am not a native Hindi speaker)
English word for a person who blindly copy others is copycat.

Ref. Cambridge dictionary
copycat.
noun [ C ].
1.disapproving
someone who is influenced by someone else and does or says exactly the same as them:
You're just a copycat!.
Whether it is the original attacker or a copycat, he must be caught soon..
Synonym
imitator.
2.something that is intentionally done or made to be very similar to something else:
Many of the drugs licensed in the last decade have been copycats of already existing medicines.

If OP is looking for a witty phrase. The funniest animal that imitates others is a monkey. The English phrase is:
Monkey see, monkey do'.
It refers to copying someone’s actions without putting much thought into it.

"Monkey see, monkey do" is a great phrase, but it doesn't really touch upon intelligence here.

@cmw One of the comments - **Good composers borrow, great ones steal," **-    They take ideas from others but improve on it. The phrase - Monkey say, monkey do - means copying blindly like a monkey without using the brain.

That's a better fit, I'd say!

I don't have sources for these, but maybe they're useful:

"It's only illegal if you get caught"
"Steal a candy bar and you go to jail; steal $1,000,000 from the candy company and you get a raise" - A justification for cheating based on the idea that everybody is already cheating, especially wealthy people.
"Work smart, not hard" - You'd usually say this about doing something the easy way, but in some cases the "easy way" could be copying work.
"There are bold thieves and old thieves, but no old, bold thieves." - The implication is that people who aren't careful at stealing get caught, so anyone who gets away with it must have some degree of talent. Usually it's about a dangerous job with a reputation for hotheadedness, like pilots or construction workers, but you also hear it used for criminals.
"To copy from one source is plagiarism, to copy from two is research" - mostly in the context of academia.
"Talent imitates; genius steals." - mostly in the context of the arts.

A literary allusion might be "Tom Sawyer whitewashing the fence", which is a Mark Twain scene where a Tom Sawyer convinces other kids to pay him to do his chores by pretending that it's a reward.

I think my IQ increased by reading this answer. :)
